# arithmetic grade for collage

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two table

```
table a 
   nim   01 01 01  02 02 02 03 03 03 04 04 04 05 05 05
   task   t  m  f   t  m   f  t  m  f  t  m  f  t  m  
   grade 70 80 85  75  65  75 70 80 85 70 80 84 72 50 65
```

**note** : t= task m=middle f=finale

```
table b 
nim 01 02 03 04 05 
name lius leo eris calvin kevin 
status A A I I A
```

**Note** : A= Avaliable , I=Invalid

Now i want to show

```
no name nim t m f t1 m1 f1 final grade

note t1= tx0.2 
m1 = mx0.3 
f1 = fx0.5
```

and status= A

**final** = sum t1,m1,f1

```
for grade
grade a >=85 
grade b>=75 
grade c >=65
```

i stuck in here

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.NIM,TM,MID,FINAL,[Poin T],[Poin M],[Poin F],FLOOR([Poin T]+[Poin M]+[Poin F])AS NilaiAkhir,
CASE WHEN ([Poin T]+[Poin M]+[Poin F])>84.9 AND ([Poin T]+[Poin M]+[Poin F])<=100 THEN 'A'
 WHEN ([Poin T]+[Poin M]+[Poin F])>74.9 AND ([Poin T]+[Poin M]+[Poin F])<=85 THEN 'B'
 WHEN ([Poin T]+[Poin M]+[Poin F])>64.9 AND ([Poin T]+[Poin M]+[Poin F])<=75 THEN 'C'
 ELSE 'D' END AS Grade
FROM Mahasiswa a,
 (SELECT NIM, TM=Nilai FROM Mahasiswa WHERE Tipe LIKE 'TM') b,
 (SELECT NIM, MID=Nilai FROM Mahasiswa WHERE Tipe LIKE 'MID')c,
 (SELECT NIM, FINAL=Nilai FROM Mahasiswa WHERE Tipe LIKE 'FINAL')d,
 (SELECT NIM, [Poin T]=Nilai*0.2 FROM Mahasiswa WHERE Tipe LIKE 'TM' )e,
 (SELECT NIM, [Poin M]=Nilai*0.3 FROM Mahasiswa WHERE Tipe LIKE 'MID' )f,
 (SELECT NIM, [Poin F]=Nilai*0.5 FROM Mahasiswa WHERE Tipe LIKE 'FINAL' )g
WHERE a.NIM=b.NIM AND a.NIM=c.NIM AND a.NIM=d.NIM AND a.NIM=e.NIM AND a.NIM=f.NIM AND a.NIM=g.NIM
```

Comment: School work? Hints: JOIN, and also GROUP BY.

Comment: can you help me. its for my task job

Answer (score 0):

```
select row_number () over (order by e.nim) as no ,    e.Nim,TM,Mid,Fin,T1,M1,F1,CEILING(T1+M1+F1) as score,
case WHEN (T1+M1+F1)>84.9 AND (T1+M1+F1)<=100 THEN 'A'
 WHEN (T1+M1+F1)>74.9 AND (T1+M1+F1)<=85 THEN 'B'
 WHEN (T1+M1+F1)>64.9 AND (T1+M1+F1)<=75 THEN 'C'
 ELSE 'D' END AS Grade
FROM
(select nim,tm,mid,fin
from Tablemhs
pivot
(
sum (grade)
for task in (Tm,Mid,Fin))as a)e,
(Select  Nim, T1= (grade*0.2) from Tablemhs where Task like 'TM') b,
(Select  Nim, M1= grade*0.3 from Tablemhs where Task like 'MID') c,
(Select  Nim, F1= grade*0.5 from Tablemhs where Task like 'FIN') d,
Tablestatus f
where e.Nim=b.nim and e.Nim=c.Nim and e.Nim=d.Nim and f.Nim=e.Nim and   status like'A'
```

any simple answer?